# How to allow language change even after detecting country?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have developed a simple script:

```
    function checkForCountry () {
      let lang = ''
      let loc = window.location.href

      switch (code) {

              case 'DE':
              case 'AT':
                lang = '/de/'
              break

              case 'IT':
                lang = '/it/'
              break

              default:
                lang = ''
            }
            if (loc.indexOf('.com') !== -1 && loc.indexOf(`${lang}`) !== -1) {
              return
            }

            return window.location.replace('example.com' + language)
          }
        }
      })
    }
checkForCountry ())
```

Ok, so it is really simple. It will read the `code` it gets via API call (didn't put API call) and depending on the `code` it will know which language to assign.

This part:

```
if (loc.indexOf('.com') !== -1 && loc.indexOf(`${lang}`) !== -1) {
  return
}
```

is to stop pilling up the `lang` and to break the cycle.

Now, when I want to change the language manually, in the website it reverts to the language I came. So, for example I have Italian version of site, and when user comes to the site he is automatically navigated to Italian version, ie.: example.com/it. If he tries to change the language to English, he always gets navigated back to Italian version.

How can I make this? I need to have this script, but when user navigates to English version of site for example: example.com, I want him to stay there.

Thank you.

Comment: If the user can manually change the language (eg. via clicking a link or by selecting an option in a dropdown menu) you could store this preference in a cookie. Then, in your script, abort the redirection if said cookie is set and the current language matches what the user selected.

Comment: @cabrerahector, thanks. Please post a working example. :)

Comment: For that, I'll ask you to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can help out. What you originally posted isn't enough -at least for me- to fully understand how your script works.

Comment: @cabrerahector, what exactly is needed besides the above? I have only left out the API call, where I get `code`